# fatal alert: certificate_expired issue push notifications using Javapns

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am getting `fatal alert: certificate_expired` when I tried to push notification for iPhone.
Previously it was working fine and suddenly it stops working.

How can I solve that issue?

Comment: Have you confirmed that are your certificate active. If yes then retry  to regenerate your certificate and then try again.

Comment: pls kindly help to answer how to confirm and how to generate? Thanks ahead.

Comment: Check your certificate in keychain or in ios Developer portal. Check this link http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_Apps_on_the_iPhone_%E2%80%93_Developer_Certificates_and_Provisioning_Profiles. Hope it'll help.

Comment: Thanks you so much cause I am just an outsider asking to track the issue :D and not familiar with the project. pls make it as an answer, so that I can accept it if that one is a real issue.